# Firestore "array-contains-any" not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use query for Firestore on iOS (Swift):

```
db.collection(FS_PICS)
            //.whereField("category", arrayContains: "Animals")
            .whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    }
                }
        }
```

It doesn't return any result with

```
// doesn't work
.whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
```

or with

```
// doesn't work
.whereField("category", in: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
```

but I have 8 result for:

```
// It works!!
.whereField("category", arrayContains: "Animals")
```

It doesn't work like OR even like AND, because it is also does't work:

```
// It works!!
.whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals"])
```

So what is the idea of this function, what should I do to get OR ?

Comment: If this returns documents: `.whereField("category", arrayContains: "Animals")` then I would fully expect this to return at least the same documents, maybe more: `.whereField("category", in: ["Animals", "Dogs"])`.  Are you sure the `in` query isn't returning what you expect?

Comment: I think it is error in Google documentation.
it should be "arrayContainsAny" not "arrayContains" for [...]

Comment: @DougStevenson "in" doesn't return anything. But arrayContainsAny: ["Animals"] - return the same result.

Comment: You can click on the name of the code sample file in the documentation and submit a pull request to get it fixed.  You can also use the "send feedback" link at the top right of the page to send feedback.

Comment: For everyone's amusement, while were are all pondering this question and throwing out answers, the sneaky Firebase folks fixed the documentation so now it's correct. [in and array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the example of the code in the documentation. It should be **arrayContainsAny**
[image]

It is correct for other languages:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Based on the screenshot, the documentation is incorrect, you're right. Some clarifications, regardless:

This is wrong:

```
.whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
```

`arrayContains` must input a singular type of what that array contains (i.e. a string array inputs a string), not a collection. `arrayContains` does not perform OR or AND operations, it only performs equals of a single instance of an element inside an array.

This is correct:

```
.whereField("category", arrayContains: "Dogs")
```

This is also correct:

```
.whereField("category", arrayContainsAny: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
```

The `arrayContainsAny` query performs an OR operation where `category` must contain "Animals" or "Dogs".

And for measure, there is also `in` which performs an OR operation on a non-collection (i.e. non-array) field. If the "category" field were just a `String` (and not an `Array`), you could perform an OR query with:

```
.whereField("category", in: ["Animals", "Dogs"])
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to state is correct but this *arrayContains must input a String, not an Array* is not clear. Also, we don't know that this code `.whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals", "Dogs"])` would be wrong for the OP's use case. Are they trying to retrieve all nodes where the field *category* (an array) contains Animals or Dogs? If so, then it is correct and is performing an OR query against the array's being searched.

Comment: `arrayContains` must input the element that the array contains—an array of strings must input one string. To perform an `OR` operation, he must use `arrayContainsAny`, which must input an array of that array's type—an array of strings must input an array of strings. And `.whereField("category", arrayContains: ["Animals", "Dogs"])` is always wrong, regardless of use case, because it's incorrect syntax, which is why he's returning 0. He just got the syntax wrong, that's all.

Comment: yes, thank you. I've attached screenshot of the documentation. There is a mistake only for Swift example.

Comment: Unless it's an array of arrays which then it would be valid but yes you're right, that is certainly a typo!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the answer and you are absolutely correct. See my comment to the OP's question.